# MySQL retrieve 2 values from different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I didn't know how to explain it in so few words as to fit it in the title. However it's not really complicated. I have 2 tables, the first called "Lines" has these 2 columns:

```
Text  PID
```

and the second called Poems these 2:

```
PID Title
```

I need to SELECT rows from the first table when they are equal to $something and then look up on the table Poems for the matching row (the one that has the same PID) and display both the Text from the first table and the Title from the second.

How can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Lines.*, Poems.* FROM Lines 
INNER JOIN Poems ON(Poems.PID = Lines.PID)
WHERE Lines.Text = 'SOME VALUE'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT l.Text, p.Title
    FROM lines l
        INNER JOIN poems p
            ON l.PID = p.PID
    WHERE l.text = 'something'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an Inner Join SQL query:

```
    SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1 INNER JOIN 
table_name2 ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
WHERE table_namex.column_n = "xyz";
```

Which implies that in you case you will use:

```
SELECT Lines.*, Poems.*
    FROM Lines l INNER JOIN Poems p
            ON l.PID = p.PID
    WHERE l.text = "xyz"
```